# Разработка под iOS на Windows без компьютера Mac возможна?

Tags: windows, ios, xamarin

Сложилась непростая ситуация. Вдруг понадобилось написать небольшое приложение под iOS, но не тут-то было. Загрузил Xamarin, установил необходимые компоненты и тут ступор, при открытии `Main.storyboard` моего проекта пишет мне:

> The iOS Designer requires an active connection to the Mac server

Собственно говоря сам скриншот сообщения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну, соответственно если нажать ссылку <kbd>Connect Mac Server</kbd>, то в последующих окнах он просит IP-адрес или имя Mac-устройства:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Понятное дело, что приложения под iOS не могут быть созданы без компилятора от Apple. Mac-компьютера у меня нет, поэтому вариант покупки и аренды отпадает.

Как я могу скомпилировать приложение под iOS? Из устройств от Apple имеется iPad и iPhone - это как-то может помочь? Может быть есть какой-нибудь общедоступный Mac Server?

Answer (score 4):

Всё получится, нужно установить MacOS на виртуалку (у меня стоит под VM Ware Workstation Pro 12), там нужно установить и настроить XCode. 
Все тулы кроссплатформ разработки генерят XCode-проект, который уже в XCode нужно открывать, собирать, устанавливать на устройства и т.д.

Только вам еще придется оформить подписку Apple Developer ($100 в год), разобраться с регистрацией устройств и приложений, созданием профайлов и сертификатов на developer.apple.com - желательно чтобы кто-то помогал :-)
Не стоит заблуждаться, что это придется сделать только в случае, если вы хотите публиковать на AppStore - это не так, без сертификата Apple Developer там чихнуть не сможете

Если $100 и так есть где пропить, тогда надо жестоко ломать всё - устройства и Xcode

Comment: А какую версию системы вы установили? Нет случайно инструкции по установке? По поводу регистрации в Apple Developer - это ни к чему, проект будет без публикации для себя 

Comment: устанавливал еще Yosemite, взял просто чей-то готовый образ на rutracker.ru - потом разумеется апгрейдил, сейчас она самая новая.
А по поводу подписки на Apple Developer - вы заблуждаетесь, без сертификата разработчика вы там чихнуть не сможете, не говоря уже чтобы "собрать для себя" - это Apple, детка ))

Answer (score 2):

1 Хакинтош

2 Виртуальная машина

Comment: Как запилить хакинтош на виртуальную машину и в какую именно виртуалку? Хакинтош нужна не ниже `OS X El Capitan`. Пробовал под VirtualBox - как-то безуспешно. Есть ли такая практика и хоть какие-то рекомендации, кроме двух пунктов?

Comment: Всё зависит от железа. Виртуалка с хакинтошем далеко не на каждом компе будет работать. Кроме этого нужно подбирать образ под твоё железо. Ищи сборку под твоё железо. Спрашивай на сайтах хакинтошников у людей с подобным железом.

Answer (score 1):

Без Мак к сожалению решить проблему не получиться. Можно попробовать решить с помощью готовых [образов VMWare](https://rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5287454) или VirtualBox. Существуют ресурсы для компиляции приложений онлайн [PhoneGap](https://build.phonegap.com/) например, но это способ для переноса web приложения (HTML+jQuery) на мобильную платформу.

Comment: Готовых образов как-то я не нашел. VirtualBox бесплатна, но запилить `macOS Sierra` не удалось в нее. VMWare - платная, не пробовал. Установка приложения на iOS-устройство меня не интересует. Ресурс для компиляции приложений, который Вы привели, пользовались? Что скажете? Можно немного более подробно по этому поводу? В Xamarin прикрутить этот ресурс можно?

Comment: Ресурс готовит приложения из HTML+jQuery Mobile, Xamarin прикрутить не получиться. VMWare плеер бесплатен. Образ Siera https://rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5287454